# C++/C# Data Marshalling not working as expected

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

On the C++ side, I have this:

```
double* s;
    bool GetLeftOutputData(double ** a, int * i) 
    {
        s = new double[4]{ 25,24.0,33.0,57.0 };
        *a = s;
        *i = 4;
        return true;
    }
```

And on the C# side, I have:

```
[DllImport("MyDLL")]
private static extern bool GetLeftOutputData(out IntPtr ptrResultVerts, out int resultVertLength);

 void TestLeftOutputData()
{
    IntPtr ptrNativeData;
    int itemsLength;

    bool success = GetLeftOutputData(out ptrNativeData, out itemsLength);
    if (!success)
    {
    Debug.Log("Faild to get left out data");
    return;
    }

    double[] SArray = new double[itemsLength];  // Where the final data will be stored.

    Debug.Log("Length: " + itemsLength);

    IntPtr p = ptrNativeData;
    for (int i = 0; i < itemsLength; i++)
    {
        Marshal.PtrToStructure(p, SArray[i]);
        p = new IntPtr(p.ToInt64() + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(double)));
    }
}
```

Code gives no error, but for some reason, double[] array is always filled with 0, i.e. no data is being copied. Where is my mistake?

Comment: The length is the issue. 'out' doesn't imply a pointer.  So the c# has a int while the c++ is using a pointer.  Not consistent.

Comment: But when I debug inside Unity C#, lenght comes properly as 4 for me and does not give any crash. Is that really the case? I.e., when I debug, that data-assign loops runs fine 4 time in a row

Comment: Shouldn't *a = s; be a = s;